# Is there a .Net equivalent to the Maven license plugin?

Tags: .net, maven, licensing

With the maven license plugin you can cause a build to fail if any of the source files does not have the required license/copyright statement present.

Is there any way to do this for .Net projects (either in Visual Studio or via NAnt) without having to build my own tool for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I couldn't find anything obvious I coded up a crude but effective .Net executable that can be invoked from the command line

Code is [here](https://bitbucket.org/rvesse/license-checker) and usage is as follows:

```
LicenseChecker.exe -directory /path/to/src -exclude-exts "ext1,ext2" -exclude "svn|bin|obj" -license-search "Copyright Blah" -license-file license.txt -fix -overwrite
```

Or look at the source of [Program.ParseOptions()](https://bitbucket.org/rvesse/license-checker/src/tip/Program.cs?at=default#cl-93) for more detail.